# Is DataLine.getMicrosecondPosition() thread-safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, javasound

Let's say I use `DataLine.write()` in one thread and read `DataLine.getMicrosecondPosition()` in another. Will the reader thread see the updates of the writer thread, or should I synchronize my code to guarantee visibility?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to accomplish here, but for situations where I wish to coordinate playback with external events, I include messaging with the playback code. For example, a counter can count the number of frames sent for playback and when reaching certain milestones, can also sent a message (via loose coupling) to another thread.

Comment: Sure I could do that, but then OTOH I don't see the point in counting the sent frames if the API provides a method for that. Now I just need to know if I have to synchronize myself, or the API guarantees that I won't see a cached value on the reader's thread.

Comment: Basically, Java doesn't offer much in the way of real-time guarantees. I've found that counting frames is the best accuracy I've been able to get in for coordinating events on and off of the audio thread. A lot depends on what you are trying to do. I'm just trying to open the door to alternatives but am limited by the lack of big-picture info. If you wish to restrict yourself to a specific technical question, I'm not your guy. But I can say that in general using synchronization, which creates blocks, on the audio thread is to be avoided as it can easily lead to dropouts.

Comment: Some issues concerning low-latency audio are explained in this paper. javax.sound.sampled has been pretty stable the last decade, afaik. https://diuf.unifr.ch/main/pai/sites/diuf.unifr.ch.main.pai/files/publications/2007_Juillerat_Mueller_Schubiger-Banz_Real_Time.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear:

`write()` is a potentially blocking call that puts data into the line's buffer *for rendering*. I.e. the line may render the data at some time in the future. From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine.html#write(byte%5B%5D,int,int)):

> The requested number of bytes of data are read from the specified array, starting at the given offset into the array, and written to the data line's buffer.

`getMicrosecondPosition ()` tells you how many microseconds *have already been* rendered, [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#getMicrosecondPosition()):

> The microsecond position measures the time corresponding to the number of sample frames captured by, or rendered from, the line since it was opened.

Both methods *should* be thread-safe, as there is no warning in the Javadocs.

Comment: That's not how I read and interpret the Javadocs. Assuming threadsafty in absence of a warning is IMO a huge fallacy.

Comment: I see your point, but if `getMicrosecondPosition()` was only returning correct values, if called from the same thread as `write()` or from within sync, I would expect this to be worth a note in the javadocs. Especially, as `write()` just places data into a buffer, which most likely is read by another thread that renders the audio. That thread is responsible for maintaining the `microsecondPosition` value. So we most likely have some interplay of threads anyway that *should* be properly synchronized. That all said, the implementation in `com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice` is synchronized.

Comment: If you call List.add() and List.get() within two different threads, you might see cached values in the reader thread. That's the nature of Java's memory model and there's no need to emphasize this in the Javadoc of List. I assume the same for DataLine's documentation.